# Formatting the date and time based on user settings, but adding a leading zero

Tags: c#, formatting

I know that I can get the correct time format from the user settings in the OS by using datetime.ToString("G"), however I would like to add the leading zeros to ensure the date/time aligns in a column.  Is there a way to format the time with leading zeros (with out using a custom format string) and get it to output in the format set by the user?

Comment: do you mean "0"+(datetime.ToString("G"));

Comment: How can you format Datetime according to user settings if you don't want to use "Custom format string"

Comment: How about `datetime.ToString("u")`?  [DateTime Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: "u" does not work because it is a universal pattern, I want to use the locale pattern, however I also want to ensure leading zeros. @husnain I guess in a way I do want to use a custom format string but I want it to be the format string that is specified by the user based on their locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "G" and "g" patterns depend on the "d" (short date) pattern.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx.

You could construct a custom `CultureInfo` or `DateTimeFormatInfo` object based on the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, but instead of copying the `ShortDatePattern` directly from the souce culture, replace any single-letter occurrence of "M" or "d" with "MM" and "dd", respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have default and custom format at the same time.

I think what you want is to look at [LongDatePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longdatepattern.aspx) to figure out order of day/month/year for particular culture and corresponding separators and create your custom string based on that.

Side notes:

- you may instead consider simply aligning your resulting value in text table by spaces.
- if you want the data to be used for anything but human consumption using universal format (potentially with UTC values) is better.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of low brow but it works...

```
                    CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

                string longtimepattern = ci.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern;
                longtimepattern = longtimepattern.Replace("m", "mm").Replace("mmmm", "mm") ;
                longtimepattern = longtimepattern.Replace("h", "hh").Replace("hhhh", "hh");
                longtimepattern = longtimepattern.Replace("H", "HH").Replace("HHHH", "HH");
                longtimepattern = longtimepattern.Replace("s", "ss").Replace("ssss", "ss");

                string shortdatepattern = ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
                shortdatepattern = shortdatepattern.Replace("d", "dd").Replace("dddd", "dd");
                shortdatepattern = shortdatepattern.Replace("M", "MM").Replace("MMMM", "MM");

                string datestr = new DateTime(obj.TestDateTime_utc).ToLocalTime().ToString(shortdatepattern + " " + longtimepattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
    {
        public static string GetLocaleDateTimeFormating(this DateTime T )  
        {
            DateTimeFormatInfo sysUIFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat;
            string customFormat = sysUIFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("d", "dd").Replace("M", "MM");
            customFormat += " " + sysUIFormat.ShortTimePattern.Replace("h", "hh").Replace("H", "HH");
            string newDate = T.ToString(customFormat);
            return newDate;
        }
    }
```

**To Get Datetime formated value**

```
 this.textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.GetLocaleDateTimeFormating();
```